# How to convert app-release.apk to app.apk

Tags: cordova, google-play, command-line-interface

I am developing an android app in Cordova by Command-Line-Interface. I have strictly follow this documentation https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/cli/index.html. and i have successfully build the application in release mode. Finally I got an apk like app-release.apk .I have added keystore and signed my app. So my question is can I directly upload this "app-release.apk" in google play or i have to make app.apk . Please consider me as novice in this platform. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly upload the app-release.apk file. The name of the apk does not matter.